# Disqus plugin not working on new wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, disqus

Disqus was working fine on all my posts until recently when it didn't show up on a couple of new posts. I tried deactivating all the plugins and installing disqus again. Nothing worked out. After checking the page source of new posts there was no code present for disqus comments unlike other posts. Please help.
[Website](http://dealsandreads.com).

Disqus not showing up for all posts after 20 January 2014

Answer (score 3):

This is likely a settings issue and not a development one - Disqus renders within the Wordpress comments template, so check a couple of things:

1. You have "Allow comments" enabled for your posts
2. In the Disqus plugin settings, you have "Use Disqus comments on" set to "On all future and existing posts"

Comment: For those struggling to find where you an allow comments on posts there are 2 things you need to do - 1) Settings > Discussion > Default Article Settings > Allow people to post comments on new articles (enable)

2) Enable on each post (if you have old posts with comments not enabled) - Posts > Select Post > Screen Options (top right) > Discussion (enable), then at the bottom of the page > Enable Discussion (enable)